# How to automate entering email and password in a config file using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

To open a service it prompt for email and password.I want when on screen it came enter email value from script got paste and automatically enter pressed.

I am new to it so tried a basic method.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads/

nordvpn --config filepath

abc@xyz.com

password
```

Comment: bash isn't the correct tool. `expect` is written to handle interactive I/O with remote systems.

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin Expect is what i was looking for

Comment: So does `( echo abc@xyz.com; echo 'password' ) | nordvpn` work?

Comment: Two other options: the `nordvpn` command might have options to pass in the username and password, or they may support a configuration file where you can put the same information.

Comment: Yes, a *credentials* file with restrictive permission may be another option.

Comment: Not a case specific to nodevpn it can be any other service who prompt and ask to type email and password. I want these sequence through bash.Expect can do but how to do it in Bash.